# FileUpload Control will be clear text in textbox after postback by dropdown

Tags: postback

I use fileupload control to upload file, but after postback page, text (filename) on textbox of fileupload control was cleared. I don't want clear it, pls tell me solution for issue

Answer (score 0):

If your `dropdownlist` does not affect any other part of your `WebForm` (i.e. if you choose a value it populates another dropdownlist's items) you can simply set the dropdowns `autopostback property` to false

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

However, if you need a postback to occur for the server to handle some code you'll need to pop the controls, effected by the postback, into an `UpdatePanel`

Controls affected by a postback in a updatepanel and your file upload outside it like so:

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, what would happen above as an example would be:

1.The `dropdownlist` changes value/index/whatever, it changes and it does a post back to execute code

2.The code executes server side and puts the new value in the textbox (`TextBox1.Text = Dropdownlist1.Text`)

3.A `postback` will occur inside `updatepanel` executing whatever code but everything outside the update panel will stay the same